# Cannot render Component passing React state to props for another Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state

I had a rather simple problem, and all the previous questions I read deal with more complicated issues, so I post it, hoping somebody can help me with this.

I Have a Main Component where I call all the other components in my app, to render them in App.js Inside this Main Component I have the Home function component, which renders the home page. I cannot manage to render the function components inside the home component. I present my code in order.

I tried to pass the state in the Main Component, which calls the file "Desc.js" to retrieve the information sent as props to the Home function Component, which in turn send this props as the variable {item} to the RenderDesc function component

this is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Main />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is MainComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './include/HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './include/FooterComponent';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import Login from './LoginComponent';
import {DESC} from '../shared/Desc.js';
import {Switch, Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      contents: DESC
    }
  }
  render(){
    const HomePage = () => {
      return(
        <Home content = {this.state.contents}
        />
      );
    }
    return(
      <div>
        <Header />
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route path = "/home" component = {HomePage} />
            <Route exact path = '/login' component = {Login} />
            <Redirect to = "/home"></Redirect>
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

This is HomeComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';

function RenderDesc({item}){

        return(
            <div id={item.desc_id} className="row row-content align-items-center">
                <div className="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <img src={item.desc_image} className="img-ex img-fluid" alt={item.desc_image_alt}/>
                </div>
                <div className="col col-sm col-md">
                    <p>{item.desc_content1}</p>
                    <p>{item.desc_content2}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
}

function Home(props){
    return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="cover-container mx-auto flex-column">
                    <div className="inner cover text-center">
                    <h1 className="cover-heading">Data to take <br />Control</h1>
                    <p className="lead">We create the efficient and effective solution
                        your organization needs to act informed and on time.</p>
                    <p className="lead">
                        <a href="#about" className="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Find out more</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <RenderDesc item={props.content}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

And this is the content of Desc.js

```
export const DESC=
[
  {
    desc_id: 1,
    desc_content1: 'As time passes, the accumulation of spreadsheets and even shared documents to manage the operation of your business in a daily basis, becomes complicated and slow down common tasks. This can significantly impact your team’s performance.',
    desc_content2: 'We develop personalized implementations to respond our customer’s needs. We aim to integral solutions that scans the processes, identify the main features and smooth the user interface with friendly tools, easy to manage.',
    desc_image: 'images/icons/phone.png',
    desc_image_alt: 'phone',
  },
  {
    desc_id: 2,
    desc_content1: 'Take the step to a real virtualization and automation of your processes can be challenging, moreover when is desired to avoid any disruption. Although, to hold competitivenes and increase efficiency, is an issue that must be addressed. When is possible, graduality is an effective strategy.',
    desc_content2: 'We develope solutions that adapts to requirements, printing on back-end and front-end developments, ease and simplicity that enables a smooth adaptation of the team. This creates trust and helps to draw their attention from the repetitive and lateral tasks, towards the operations that requires the professional’s criteria and flexibility.',
    desc_image: 'images/icons/mind.png',
    desc_image_alt: 'mind',
  }
]
```

But in the end, the content in Desc.js is never rendered. Help please

Comment: the stuff in `DESC` is an array of objects. are you trying to get just one item from the array? or are you expecting a list of items to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Your content is [] of {}. You should map it and iterate it.

```
function RenderDesc({items}){

return(
   items.map(item=>(<div id={item.desc_id} className="row row-content align-items-center">
   <div className="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
       <img src={item.desc_image} className="img-ex img-fluid" alt=    {item.desc_image_alt}/>
   </div>
   <div className="col col-sm col-md">
       <p>{item.desc_content1}</p>
       <p>{item.desc_content2}</p>
   </div>
</div>))
);
}

function Home(props){
return(
   <div className="container">
       <div className="cover-container mx-auto flex-column">
               <div className="inner cover text-center">
               <h1 className="cover-heading">Data to take <br />Control</h1>
               <p className="lead">We create the efficient and effective solution
                   your organization needs to act informed and on time.</p>
               <p className="lead">
                   <a href="#about" className="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Find out more</a>
               </p>
           </div>
       </div>
       <RenderDesc items={props.content}/>
   </div>
);
}
```

Comment: thanks! I tried iterating but I guess my code was too flawed. Yours works perfect!

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` is an array. Yet, you seem to be trying to render it as if it were a single object. Try changing...

```
<RenderDesc item={props.content}/>
```

in the `Home` component to...

```
{props.content.map(item => <RenderDesc key={item.desc_id} item={item}/>)}
```

This will render one `RenderDesc` for each object in the `DESC` array